# Google Analytics doesn't record adwords conversion

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I use an I-Frame where there are 3 steps to complete an order. On the last step the conversion is recorded. The adword will link to the page which includes the I-Frame, from there the users has to go through the 3 steps in the I-Frame.

In the I-Frame the following functions are used: Multiple GA accounts (main website and I-Frame website), Google Enhanced E-Commerce, Adwords conversion on last page.

As you can see on the images below the conversions of Adwords doesn't show up in Google Analytics, in Google Adwords is everything OK.

Does anyone know where I have to look for to get the conversions of Adwords in Google Analytics?

**Image 1:**
[image: Image 1]

**Image 2:**
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

What type of goal do you have this setup as in Analytics?

You can use the drop down filter to display different goals in your table view as shown [here](http://screencast.com/t/kLjWK3nIXUV)

You can also use the Explorer tabs above the chart to have your table display only goal 1, goal 2, or ecommerce related data.

Does that help?

Comment: I need the conversions of the E-Commerce. But also all my other goals have 0% Conversion. Maybe it has something to do with gclid?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not properly share the Google Analytics client ID between your main site and the iFrame (which I suppose is being served from a different host / domain). As a result of this, the conversions within the iFrame are being attributed to a referral coming from your main web site instead of Paid Search.

In order to provide the correct client ID to Google Analytics inside your iFrame, you need to pass it from the main web site. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#iframes) for an idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the basics is that conversions measured by adWords script is going to calculate the conversions with its own attribution model, which is going to be different from conversions being measured by analytics (defaut or custom model): https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2679221?hl=en

You can measure data on GA by setting up either a google analytics conversion or a goal tag on the last page. 
Details here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722054?hl=en